# Auto Gitpull Script?

Tags: php, git, automation, git-pull

I want to create a script for git which is triggered when there is an update to a repo and does "git pull" on our remote server.

I have a very basic version in which a POST message is set to the URL on our server which would have the content

```
<?php `git pull`;
```

In it, no problem there. However the dev domain is actually a fake domain which nginx redirects to on my server (url.dev) so I can't point to it this way. My idea was to point another live domain to a subfolder on the dev server, so the top level directory can't be accessed, but then of course running "git pull" from that directory won't work. Is there anyway in PHP to run the command so that it "CD"'s into the correct director and Gitpulls or is this not possible with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the public keys to the user that is running your scripts (usually www-data) you can do this

```
    system("/path/to/executable/git pull;echo \"\nLast commit\";  /path/to/executable/git log -2;");
```

Comment: how would I run this? as a php script?

Comment: yes, first thing make sure that the www-data user can login to the git server via ssh keys, then try a git pull and if it all works this script will do the same thing.

Comment: ok great, i'll give this a go. At the moment my user is nginx. Unfortunately I can't swap the nginx users via command line, so its hard to see if I can do it or not, there is no home folder or anything for it.

Comment: you can do this: login as root, then su nginx, see if you can create your keys with ssh-keygen -t rsa, if it complains that you don't have a home directory create that with root and chown it to nginx. after that you can create the keys. once you upload the public key to the git server try again git pull with the nginx user if it works it will work via php as well

Comment: Ok, I can't Su as nginx it says "This account is currently not available." however I was able to create an SSH key for it with sudo from root, and put it in a folder for it, so I've copied the public part to bitbucket, so now my php script should look like this right?

<?php  system("ssh nginx@127.0.0.1 'cd /var/www/vhosts/development/; git pull;echo \"\nLast commit\";  git log -2;'");

Comment: hmmm, that didn't work for me, still doesn't pull anything. I tried just a simple <?php `cd /var/www/vhosts/development && git pull`; seen as the nginx user has the ssh key now too, but nothing.

Comment: no, you are doing it wrong, if you can't su as nginx it means that the webserver is not running as nginx you should see the actual user via phpinfo(). about my script, sorry I made a huge mistake, there's no need for you to use ssh, I've edited it.

Comment: Ok I've got it working with the SSH key now, although its stored in /var/cache/ which I'm worried will get deleted (as nginx is a worker process with no home directory) but at the moment if I type "sudo -u nginx git pull" whilst in the development directory at command line it does a git pull fine.

However the php script still doesn't work. Have I entered the wrong details in your version? I tried my version with a simple cd into directory and git pull too, neither are pulling the changes

Comment: ok, you are almost done, try to remove the cd part and just upload the php file in the correct directory, also it could be possible that there's no $PATH declared for that user so you need to invoke the absolute path for the git binary

Comment: yes your last changed worked! My only worry is now, because nginx is just a worker process and its using the /var/cache directory that its ssh key is going to get wiped... I can't find anywhere online instructions to add a home directory that is uses which is safe and constant.

Comment: great! well, it's easy, if you have access to root just edit the /etc/passwd file and modify nginx home directory accordingly

Comment: sorted that, done all the above, put it in a sub director, created a URL for it, and if I fire it in my browser it works perfectly. Popped into into bit buckets POST section and, doesn't do a thing?!!

Comment: Have I got to do something different for this script to work on a POST hook? Because ive just tried in Gitlab and its not working there either??

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, what's that?

Comment: On bitbucket (or github, or gitlab) this script is triggered by their POST hook, when I git push, the script should be triggering doing a pull on my remote server. The script works fine but the POST hook isn't triggering it. I wonder if it needs to do something different as its not being parsed in a browser now?

Comment: have you sure that bitbucket is actually sending a POST request to your server? can it reach it? are there any authentications that need to be done? check nginx logs and see if the url is actually called.

Comment: Hmmm, I've looked through logs and can't see any reference to it. I don't see why it wouldn't reach it, if I can open it in my browser successfully the POST request should be getting through? It's only sending on port 80 right?

Comment: Ok this is in an access log...

131.103.20.165 - - [19/Feb/2014:14:04:11 -0500] "POST /gitautopull.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33 "-" "Bitbucket.org" "-"

Comment: Do I need to add something like...

if ( $_POST['payload'] ) {

to receive the POST and do something with it?

Comment: Hmm tried the 'Payload' but still nothing happening - the nginx log seems to show that is receiving the command?

Comment: I can run the php script from both browser and terminal just fine, run from terminal as the web server user (nginx) by going "sudo -u nginx php script.php" and it outputs and runs just fine. Nginx can SSH into bitbucket, everything is working except for some reason the POST request inexplicably doesn't trigger it??!

Comment: Nope, there are some "undefined Payload" messages in the error log from when I was experimenting with that, but I've put it back to your original script which works in the browser just fine and no error message, it received POST request at 25mins past on the server time and there are no error messages for that or anytime after it.

Comment: It must be an nginx config or something, its the only thing left I can think of.

Comment: i doubt it's nginx fault, add some logs to the page

Comment: Got it, it was a permission issue I was missing before! The nginx user could log into bitbucket but it could create files in the .git directory. Now I've got a "Deploy" user that I use for capistrano deployments, it has full sudo access, so its as good as root really, I've added nginx to the deploy group and now I've made the files part of the deploy group so it appears the nginx worker can write to them - is there any security danger with this? I'm not sure how to keep a git pull creating them as that too if I do a manual one from the command line for instance

Comment: maybe it would be better for you to schedule a git pull each minute via crontab, ideally files in the web directory should not match the same user as the http server

Comment: they shouldn't? Why? If the web server creates any files it creates them with its own user, so they are owned nginx:nginx. This is the only way to allow wordpress etc to write to its own path as well. When I deploy to production I have it run chmod -R nginx:nginx so that the server can read and write to all the files.

Comment: yes, I know, but if the software you are running has a breach it will be able to write or modify files, which is usually not a good thing :)

Comment: that's why in my first example i was logging via ssh to the same server, but with a different user

Comment: so would you usually have root own all the web directories and just 777 an upload directory (or have that specific directory owned by the nginx user?) Normally I always see apache:apache, nginx:nginx or www-data:www-data own all the files int eh web directory

Comment: no, I usually use an extra account, and put files in the webdirectory with that user. setting all to 777 means trouble. I understand that wordpress needs to be able to write files, and for such occasions I chown to www-data, after that, back to the extra account. you DON'T want your web directory to be writable, there are a lots of ways for you to be attacked